# How to do permanent text color change in TextView selected item in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-selector

I want to make permanent color change on key press on a TextView.

Here is my color selector resides in res/color folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#a7524a"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#a7524a"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#a7524a"/>
<item android:color="#595959"/>
</selector>
```

In TextView I refer it as

```
android:textColor="@color/bright_text_dark_focused"
```

It works fine. I want to make the color change permanent when user a presses a TextView item and releases. By default it goes to the default color on release.

Update:

I have changed the color selector as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">      
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#a7524a"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:color="#a7524a" />   
<item android:color="#595959"/>    
</selector>
```

This is working as same before. I have added

```
android:textIsSelectable = "true"
```

property in the TextView . Then the background color on selection property disappears. But the text color becomes permanent when I click on the items. Any clue for why this happens? Actually I have this textview inside a listview. The background color property is from ListView.

Comment: have you read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you added the line `<item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/bright_text_dark_focused"/>` then enable the `TextView` on touch, it would stay.  This is the case so long as you never disable it.

Comment: I have added this line. The app stopped from launching.

Comment: is there a possibility to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you you mean it stopped launching?  This line shouldn't have any affect on launch.

Answer (score 0):

android:state_activated must solve your problem:

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#fff"/>
```

You may olso set this for your listView:

```
mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

and when listView item clicked this:

```
mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
```